# Exporting to PDF from print composer in QGIS with two maps on layout?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm using QGIS Desktop 2.10.1, and I created a print composer with two different maps.  The maps are based on the same shapefile, but each has a different variable and thus a different color scheme (one blue, one green).  To create them, I duplicated my shapefile in the main window and applied a different variable to each copy.  When I attempt to export my map to pdf, the resulting pdf looks fine except that instead of the two different maps, it has simply duplicated the first one where the second should be.  However, the print composer still looks correct and has two distinct maps.  I have locked both map layers.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have locked the layers styles?